# How to use FPU View of Delphi to find the program bug?

Tags: delphi

I met some questions in the development of Delphi
,but I don't know where`s the problem in.

To what extent is the FPU View helpful to find an error and how to use it.

Comment: The fpu view shows the fp registers. That's it. It won't find bugs for you. You'll have to do that.

Comment: I may express wrong .
I mean I want to find the bug ,but I dont know how to use the tool(FPU View).
I cant understand the reason of those information.

Comment: The FPU view just displays the state of the FPU registers. You read the documentation I hope? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FPU

Comment: thank you for your reason. I just want to try finding Bug from FPU
I just try something. 
I`m junior in learning Delphi.
Not mean I want someone to help  me solve it

Comment: You'll need to show more concrete details. The documentation is quite complete. Please read it. If you don't understand it, explain in detail what you don't understand. Provide examples to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FPU stands for Floating Point Unit. FPU View is the list of the "mathematical coprocessor" registers, and is usually used together with CPU View (Central Processor Unit, AKA processor).

This is definitelly not for beginners, nor for people which do not know PC assembly language. Don't worry - I don't believe you will ever need to use these views, anyhow. Just stick with the "regular" debugger views.